# Can only the return of a function be called instead of other instructions in it?

Tags: python, function, return, calculator

I am trying to program a simple calculator using the following script:

```py
def math(num_1, num_2):
    global operation
    if operation == '+':
        x = num_1 + num_2
    elif operation == '-':
        x = num_1 - num_2
    elif operation == '*':
        x = num_1 * num_2
    elif operation == '/':
        x = num_1 / num_2
    return float(x)

def opp():
    print("To add, press '+'")
    print("To add, press '-'")
    print("To multiply, press '*'")
    print("To divide, press '/'")

def inp():
    num_1 = input("Enter first number: ")
    num_2 = input("Enter second number: ")
    return float(num_1), float(num_2)

a, b = inp()

opp()
operation = input()

result = math(a, b)

print("The result is: " + str(result))
```

It works by asking for the 2 numerical inputs first and then the operation.
I am trying to have it ask for the operation in between the 2 numerical inputs.
For that, I want the following:

```py
def opp():
    print("To add, press '+'")
    print("To add, press '-'")
    print("To multiply, press '*'")
    print("To divide, press '/'")
    operation = input()
    return operation

def inp():
    num_1 = input("Enter first number: ")
    opp()
    num_2 = input("Enter second number: ")
    return float(num_1), float(num_2)
```

And then I want to input the output of `opp()` into `math()`, but when I try to replace the `operation` variable in `math()` with `opp()`, then the entire `opp()` function executes, including its print statements.

Is there a way to input the return of `opp()` into `math()`?

running Python 3.8.3 on Windows 10

Comment: No, you can't execute selective parts of a function without having explicit `if` checks within the function and passing in a flag or something. If you don't want part of a function to execute, take that part out into its own function. Part of the problem here is that `opp` is doing too much. It's printing a menu, and asking for input. If you only want of those parts to run in some cases, that functionality should be in its own function (although, in this specific case, you might as well just use `input` directly).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `global` - that's a bad way to move data around inside a program.  Instead, just return `operation` from `inp()`, and pass it as a parameter to `math()`.

```py
def math(operation, num_1, num_2):
    if operation == '+':
        x = num_1 + num_2
    elif operation == '-':
        x = num_1 - num_2
    elif operation == '*':
        x = num_1 * num_2
    elif operation == '/':
        x = num_1 / num_2
    return float(x)

def opp():
    print("To add, press '+'")
    print("To add, press '-'")
    print("To multiply, press '*'")
    print("To divide, press '/'")
    operation = input()
    return operation

def inp():
    num_1 = input("Enter first number: ")
    operation = opp()
    num_2 = input("Enter second number: ")
    return operation, float(num_1), float(num_2)

operation, a, b = inp()

result = math(operation, a, b)

print("The result is: " + str(result))
```

Example:

```
Enter first number: 2
To add, press '+'
To add, press '-'
To multiply, press '*'
To divide, press '/'
*
Enter second number: 3
The result is: 6.0
```